# Using XML RPC to import data into WordPress

Tags: xml-rpc

I've been asked to create a website in WordPress that should display many phone operators/agents who can be called from a given phone number on the website.

So far so good but the website should also display to status of the agents status (available, away, busy etc) in realtime. The agents use external software for this and the data to show their availability is available through XML RPC. En example of a response can be seen below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <methodResponse>
  <params> 
   <param> 
   <value> 
    <struct> 

    <member> 
     <name>param1</name> 
     <value><string>value1</string></value> 
   </member> 

   <member> 
    <name>param2</name> 
    <value><string>value2</string></value> 
   </member>

  </struct> 
 </value> 
</param> 

</params> 
</methodResponse>
```

Is this even possible as I can't hardly find any information about importing non-WordPress data with XML RPC. The information that I've found is either outdated or really unclear and confusing to me.

If anyone know if it is possible to display the received data/status into a (custom) post type in WordPress please let me know. Or if anyone has more information about this please let me know.

Comment: XML RPC is a _remote POSTING_ protocol. So the software would need to ping your WP install and update values. Is that even the case or do you need to _pull/fetch_ data from that software?

Comment: We need to pull/fetch the data from the software into WordPress.

Comment: Well, then you need to reverse your question: "Fetch data from third party application" ... and add a tremendous amount of information how the 3rd party app exposes data (in an [edit]). For example: Does it have a rest interface and do you have the possibility to fetch the app data from some server? Also: Add what exact app that would be (incl. vendor link). So far I see it as _too localized_ and not helpful for later visitors. Depending on your [edit] we can maybe leave it open or else need to close it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kaiser. I've never done anything like this as you already may have noticed. The information that I've received from the app provider is very very limited too. I will contact them and ask for the information that you asked for.